# Django template inheritance - markup CSS class

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I would like to make a master.html for inheritance, but my problem is that in 3 different places the code is the same except the body class.

So I have master.html

```
<html>
 <head>...<head>
 <body>
  {% block one %}{% endblock %}
  {% block two %}{% endblock %}
  {% block extra %}{% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

But in some places I have 
    <_body class="front">
    <_body class="not_front"> 
The rest of my content (like .js files, images) is the same.

Is there any clean way do it right and not to have three different 'masters'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a block inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<html>
    <head>...<head>
    <body {% block body_options %}{% endblock %}>
        {% block one %}{% endblock %}
        {% block two %}{% endblock %}
        {% block extra %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your child templates,

```
{% extends 'master.html' %}
{% block body_options %}class="front"{% endblock %}
```